# Hive: Convert string with format yyyyyMMddHmmss.SSSSSSS to timestamp type

Tags: sql, datetime, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am modifying the data type to move the data to the hive.
The data is in the following format:

```
20221002060113.5896430
20221002102706.1747960
20221002094410.7570130
20221002082244.3088750
20221002070653.5202430
20221002052930.1846300
20221002070419.3333240
20221002091636.2612740
20221002061255.2212480
20221002130224.1436890
20221002050019.3692290
20221002075419.9681030
20221002081900.3694800
20221002071155.1969230
20221002100025.2322450
20221002045419.1629670
20221002043305.5806050
```

It needs to be transferred to the timestamp format, but it doesn't work as a function I know.

Below is the code I wrote:

```
SELECT 
cast(substring(test1, 1,4)||'-'||substring(test1, 5,2)||'-'||substring(test1, 7,2)||' '||substring(test1, 9,2)||':'||substring(test1, 11,2)||':'||substring(test1, 13,2)as timestamp) as tst1
FROM TEST.TESTTB
```

Write it in this way, I can convert it to timestamp format, but there are some missing values. Besides, this code is very dirty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're almost there.

```
SELECT 
cast(substring(test1, 1,4)||'-'||substring(test1, 5,2)||'-'||substring(test1, 7,2)||' '||substring(test1, 9,2)||':'||substring(test1, 11,2)||':'||substring(test1, 13,2) ||substr(test1, 15) as timestamp) as tst1
FROM TEST.TESTTB
```

Pls note, i have added last substring. Cast will convert `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSS` to a timestamp. Pls validate if it can convert whole milliseconds. If it cant, you need to trim number of milliseconds.